# Algorithm to make every number in a set positive but keep the ratios between them?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, algorithms, ratio

I don't know what tags to use for this question so if I am using the wrong ones, please suggest others.

I have a set of numbers (`ex: -20, -3, 5, 8, 30`). I need to make them greater than zero but preserve the ratios between them. However, if all I do is add `21` to each, the ratios change. For instance,

$5 / -20 = -0.25$

but

$26 / 1 = 26$ (added `21` to the above)

and

$8 / -20 = -0.4$

but

$29 / 1 = 29$. (added `21` to the above)

And if we divide `-0.25` by `-0.4` we get `0.625` while if we divide `26` by `29` we get `~0.897` so the ratios are not the same. Does anyone know how to preserve the ratios between the numbers in the set but make all the numbers positive?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you, I am looking it over now.

Comment: You can't - it's impossible to make a negative ratio like -0.4 or -0.25 using only positive numbers. If you just want to preserve magnitudes but not signs, just take the absolute value of all numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we have the set {1,2,4,-8} we can see that the ratios including -8 will always be negative and the ratios not including -8 will always be positive eg. $\frac{-8}{2}=-4$ and $\frac{2}{4}=0.5$ so we cannot make -8 positive without changing the ratios, however if we ignore the negative sign using the absolute value function denoted as |x| then we don't have negatives eg. $\frac{|-8|}{|2|}=\frac{8}{2}=4=|-4|$ we will preserve the absolute values of ratios while not including negatives.